# Get the select value from a combobox that is bound to a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to get the select value from a combobox that is bound to a dataset.

For binding the combobox I use:

```
cboEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables["employees"];
cboEmployees.ValueMember = "employee_number";
cboEmployees.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
```

To get selected value:

```
string SelectedValue = cboEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I got this error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use tags to make it clear what technology we are talking about - "c#" is not enough, it could be webforms, winforms or some other framework. I've added ASP .NET and WebForms tags to your question, as I think that is the framework you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

you should be setting the `cboEmployees.ItemsSource`. The reason for the error is because your:

`cboEmployees.SelectedValue` is null and `ToString()` method can not be called on it.

EDIT: just thinking about this more and I think should be used like so:

```
cboEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables("Employee");
cboEmployees.ValueMember = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
cboEmployees.DisplayMember = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();
```

col[0] is employee number and col[1] would be employee_name

Hope this helps!!!